# Include another nodejs app (that is run via child_process) while building electronjs app using electron-builder

Tags: electron, desktop-application, electron-builder, electron-packager

1. I have an electronjs app that is run a nodejs app via `child_process` and it creates a JSON file as output and this JSON file is being sent to the client via IPC.
    It working as expected in development mode. But if build this electronjs app using `electron-builder` it's not included that nodejs app, so I'm getting an error says `no such file or directory open ${timestamp}.json` (This file should be created by that nodejs app).

[image: This error shown after build]

2. Here is the project structure

[image]

3. Some code example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71455180/is-there-any-way-that-i-can-run-child-process-in-electronjs-and-send-json-file-t),

```json
{
  "name": "electron-ipc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "electron-builder -w -c.extraMetadata.main=main.js"
  },
  "extraFiles": [
    "anotherNodeJsApp"
  ],
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^17.1.2",
    "electron-builder": "^22.14.13"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, so the directory structure between development and build are different. If your config script has a hard-wired path where your `.json` file is saved then you will most likely have problems. Alternatively, if your Electron application is looking for your `.json` file in a specific hard-wired path then the same problems will occur. Have you thought about saving your `.json` file in one of the users commonly use [paths](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/app#appgetpathname)? If so, then you would want to pass this path to your config script and look for `.json` file in the same path.